# The ouput in the html page is not correct . Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am new to flask and I would like to create a web page which should have an input allowing us to type in a list of words and submit , then display the resulting list with occurrences ordered by frequency and alphabetically.

This is my function counting the occurrences word.py:

```
    def word_occur(List):
        dict_= dict()
        L_prime = [] 
        cpt = 0
        for i in range(len(List)):
            word_occ =  List[i] 
            if word_occ not in L_prime: 
                for word in List:
                    if word_occ == word:
                        cpt += 1
                dict_[List[i]] = cpt 
                L_prime.append(List[i]) 
                cpt = 0

        L_sort = sorted(dict_.items(),key = lambda x :(-x[1],x[0])) 
        print(L_sort)
        return L_sort
```

My flask function test_1.py

```
    app = Flask(__name__)
    @app.route('/',methods = ["POST","GET"])


    def accueil():
        List = [] 
        if request.method == "POST":
            List = request.form['List']
        result = word_occur(List)
        return render_template("accueil.html",result = result)

    if __name__ =='__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

```
My html page : accueil.html /
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Word Occurrence</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <p>Enter your list of object</p>

    <form method="POST">
        <p><input name="List" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Find occurrence" /></p>
    </form>

    <p>
        <label name="result">The result is {{result}}</label>
    </p>
</html>
```

For this input List :

```
    ["apple","lemon","banana","apple","apple","banana","lime","apricot"]
```

The output of the html page is :

```
    [('"', 16), ('a', 10), (',', 7), ('p', 7), ('e', 5), ('l', 5), ('n', 5), ('b', 2), ('i', 2), ('m', 2), ('o', 2), (' ', 1), ('[', 1), (']', 1), ('c', 1), ('r', 1), ('t', 1)]
```

But my function word.py return that :

```
    [('apple', 3), ('banana', 2), ('apricot', 1), ('lemon', 1), ('lime', 1)]
```

Please can someone tell me how can I solve that ? I am new to flask

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `List` input is submitted as a string when you're expecting a list of strings. Try using [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to convert it to a list.

E.g. assuming your list is separated by commas:

```
List = request.form['List'].split(',')
```

Edit: Per comment, if you're entering a string representation of the list, try [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to run the evaluate the string as a Python literal:

```
List = ast.literal_eval(request.form['List'])
```

Comment: But in this case it returns : ``` [('"apple"', 2), ('"banana"', 2), (' ["apple"', 1), ('"apricot"]', 1), ('"lemon"', 1), ('"lime"', 1)] ``` , which is not exactly the output of my function.

Comment: So the text you're entering is the string output of an actual list object. It's not recommended to do it like this, but if it can't be helped, you can try `ast.literal_eval`. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try converting your dictionary into a [JSON string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), although I wouldn't be surprised if Flask would already do that for you.